# Let explorer wait for copy to finish

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

Lets assume, I have an external USB drive with the following content:

```
Ü:\
    Folder1\
        Data1.file
        Data2.file
        Junk1.file
    Folder2\
        Data3.file
        Junk2.file
```

I want to copy the `Data` files to my PC with Windows Explorer. I mark `Data1.file` and `Data2.file` and initiate copying them, then I go to `Data3.file` and initiate another copying process.

What I see: Both processes are carried out simultaneously, letting the USB HDD jump between the two files being copied currently. This slows down everything, right!?

Is there any possibility to let the second copying wait for the first one to complete? Without having to wait for giving the second command, of course?

Answer (score 0):

[Copy Handler](https://www.copyhandler.com/) can do this.

Relevant [settings](https://www.copyhandler.com/configuration):

> - Intercept standard Windows operations - specifies, if Copy Handler should attempt to intercept standard Windows operations.
> - Limit maximum operations running simultaneously to ... - it allows to limit maximum count of operations pending at once. When we specify 0 - we remove limitation.

Set the limit to 1 and you'll get a queue. You can manage the queue, pause/unpause tasks etc. You can also manually force any task to start despite the limit being reached.